# Join two tables get count without using any where condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two tables, prcshd (head table) and prcsdt (detail table), and need to get count of prod_prcshd_id in prcsdt (detail table) without using where (if required can use sub-query). Not sure ...

Tried like

```
select distinct count(b.prod_prcshd_id), b.prod_prcshd_id
from tra_pharmacy_prod_prcshd a join
     tra_pharmacy_prod_prcsdt b
     on b.prod_prcshd_id = a.id
group by b.dt_id
```

My tables:

`prcshd` (head table)

```
id(pk) | medi_name_id  |  med_prep_id
 1        83                  1
 2        83                  2
```

`prcsdt` (detail table)

```
dt_id(pk) | prod_prcshd_id(fk) | type_id | prod_name_id |medi_prep_id
1            1                  4          83             1
2            1                  5          83             1
3            1                  6          83             1
4            2                  4          83             2
```

still no luck.

```
id  | prod_prcshd_id | medi_name_id
1         3              83
2         1              83
```

Comment: @sorry for bad alignment

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  (2) Edit your question and describe what *results* you want to get.  The question is unclear.

Comment: please specify desired output...

Comment: PLZ. check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem.  But, you almost *never* need `select distinct` with `group by`.  I suspect you want one of these this:

```
select b.prod_prcshd_id, count(b.prod_prcshd_id)
from tra_pharmacy_prod_prcshd a join
     tra_pharmacy_prod_prcsdt b
     on b.prod_prcshd_id = a.id
group by b.prod_prcshd_id;
```

Under most circumstances, you don't even need the `join`:

```
select ppp.prod_prcshd_id, count(*)
from tra_pharmacy_prod_prcsdt ppp
group by ppp.prod_prcshd_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for time. Working fine